# How can I pass a regular expression constant as an argument to a function?

Tags: awk, gawk

From gawk manual

> Because some built-in functions (e.g. `match`, `split`, `sub`) accept regexp constants as arguments,
>   confusion can arise when attempting to use regexp constants as
>   arguments to user-defined functions. For example:
>
> ```
> function mysub(pat, repl, str, global)
> {
> if (global)
> gsub(pat, repl, str)
> else
> sub(pat, repl, str)
> return str
> }
> {
> ...
> text = "hi! hi yourself!"
> mysub(/hi/, "howdy", text, 1)
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the programmer wants to pass a regexp constant to the
>   user-defined function `mysub()`, which in turn passes it on to either
>   `sub()` or `gsub()`. However, what really happens is that the `pat`
>   parameter is assigned a value of either one or zero, depending upon
>   whether or not `$0` matches `/hi/`. gawk issues a warning when it sees
>   a regexp constant used as a parameter to a user-defined function,
>   because passing a truth value in this way is probably not what was
>   intended.

1. How can I pass a regular expression constant as an argument to a
   function, so that the function can receive the argument as a regular
   expression instead of a truth value?

   In other word, before a regular expression constant is passed into a
   function, how can I prevent it from being evaluated as a string
   matching expression, and ensure it being treated as what it is?
2. How can regular expression constants be passed to those builtin
   functions (e.g. `match`, `split`, `sub`) as regular expressions,
   without being evaluated as a string matching expression?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use quotes to pass regular expressions as arguments to functions: `mysub("hi", "howdy", text, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes to pass values to function variables.

```
mysub( "hi", "howdy", text, 1)
```

Or using some other name for a variable:

```
thisarg = "hi"
mysub( thisarg, "howdy", text, 1)
```

Comment: This will fail for some cases, eg. when you want to pass a regex containing special characters. "warning: escape sequence `\w' treated as plain `w'"